# Parse meter readings from CSV file

Tags: c#, asp.net, classes

I have a class representing meter readings:

```
public class MeterReading
    {
        public double AccountId { get; set; }
        public DateTime MeterReadingDateTime { get; set; }
        public double MeterReadValue { get; set; }
    }
```

I also have a collection of `MeterReadings` called `MeterReadingParseResult`:

```
public class MeterReadingsParseResult : MeterReadingsBase
{
}
```

This inherits from MeterReadingBase

```
public class MeterReadingsBase
{
    private List<MeterReading> meterReadings = new List<MeterReading>();
    public List<MeterReading> MeterReadings { get => meterReadings; set => meterReadings = value; }
    public int FailedParseReadings { get; set; }
}
```

The main method I am concerned with takes in an `IFormFile` which is a CSV and using the help of the `CSVHelper` NuGet packages I can validate the CSV file content, pass it into my `MeterReading` class and add it to my `MeterReadingParseResult` collection. The `CSVHelper` code is usually a few lines of code but some of the CSV file may contain words where it needs to be doubles so I have had to customise it to make the validation suit my purpose.

```
   public class MeterReadingsCsvProcessor
    {
        private readonly IMeterReadingsRepository _meterReadingsRepository;
        private readonly IAccountsRepository _accountsRepository;
        private MeterReadingsParseResult _parseResult;

        public MeterReadingsCsvProcessor(
            IMeterReadingsRepository meterReadingsRepository, IAccountsRepository accountsRepository)
        {
            _meterReadingsRepository = meterReadingsRepository;
            _accountsRepository = accountsRepository;
            _parseResult = new MeterReadingsParseResult();
        }

        public MeterReadingsParseResult CsvHandler(IFormFile file)
        {
            if (file == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(file));

            ParseCsv(file);

            var accounts = _accountsRepository.GetAccounts();

            return _parseResult;
        }


        private void ParseCsv(IFormFile file)
        {
            TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream());
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(textReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                csv.Read();
                csv.ReadHeader();

                CsvCustomErrorHandler<int> customInt32Converter = new CsvCustomErrorHandler<int>();

                int lineNumber = 0;

                while (csv.Read())
                {
                    lineNumber++;
                    var meterReading = new MeterReading();
                    {
                        meterReading.AccountId = csv.GetField<int>("AccountId");

                        meterReading.MeterReadingDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact
                            (csv.GetField("MeterReadingDateTime"),
                            "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                        meterReading.MeterReadValue = csv.GetField<int>("MeterReadValue", customInt32Converter);
                        if (meterReading.MeterReadValue < 1 || meterReading.MeterReadValue >= 100000)
                        {
                            _parseResult.FailedParseReadings++;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    _parseResult.MeterReadings.Add(meterReading);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Can I refactor this code in anyway to make it look cleaner or in your opinions do you think I have done the best with the functionality I need to achieve?

Comment: why are using casting `AccountId` and `MeterReadValue` to `int` while they're `double` ? and why not using `CalssMap` and implements a custom `TypeConverter` instead ?

Comment: `accounts` doesn't seem to be used, so why is the code there? `_meterReadingsRepository` also isn't used.

Answer (score 4):

**1. Document your code**

While it seems a bit boring and useless to do now, in 6 months you will read your code again and it will take some time to remember what this class/field/property is used for...

The minimum would be to document with XML comments all the public parts. You can type three slashes `///` and Visual Studio will insert the following :

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
```

In summary you can insert a short description for the item you are documenting. This will be visible in Visual Studio IntelliSense and can be really helpful.

**2. Property Consistency**

Everywhere you use autoproperties with no private field. Except once, for a List. Why is it not another autoproperty ?

```
public List<MeterReading> MeterReadings { get; set; } = new List<MeterReading>();
```

**3. Field naming conventions**

At some point, a private field start with a low case letter. Somewhere else you start your private fields with an underscore. Keep it consistent by writing them always with the same convention. There are no strict rules, so you just have to be consistent with yourself (which is not always easy) or your team (which is even harder).

On a personal matter, I don't like underscores because it is used by the compiler to generate some backing fields in the background, and I don't want to be interfering with that.

**4. Unused Variables**

You have unused variables. That could be a good startup to code cleaning. Every variable you write will take you some time to read and understand why it's there. If the variable is not used, you waste time understanding why it's not used...

Maybe it is used in other parts of your code, but since you did not mention it, I will assume it is not used anywhere else.

- `_meterReadingsRepository` : you set it in the constructor, then never again. Is it because the constructor should look like this ? Because it comes from another public interface on which you have no control ? This can happen, but commment it then, so you know why you wasted so time creating a variable you are not using.
- `int lineNumber = 0;` : you set this value and increment it every iteration. Very nice. But you never actually read the value, so what's the point ? Debug issue ?
- `private MeterReadingsParseResult _parseResult;` : You use this variable to store the csv parsing results, which is fine. But you never use it again. So you memorize it, maybe to save some time the next time the parsing method is called ? But you recreate it anyway ! So the variable is completely useless.
- `var accounts = _accountsRepository.GetAccounts();` : This one is almost like magic... What is this call supposed to do ? Because you never use the accounts variable. Maybe the method itself does something important for the rest, but there is no way to know...

**5. Type consistency**

The fields AccountId & MeterReadValue are of type double but when you parse them from csv they are supposed to be int. Why ? Are they supposed to be integer or double ?

If they are supposed to be doubles, you have a bug and you should parse them as double instead of int.

If they are supposed to be int, there is no need to make the properties double. Unless you have a real reason for that, in which case you should add a comment to explain why they are double but parsed as int.

**6. Null checks**

You check for null once. Which is good. But what about the rests. Should you be checking for nulls in the constructor, where you receive two values and assign them to your private fields ?

**7. The method's job**

What is the method `CsvHandler` doing exactly ?

- First, it checks that the file is not null.
- Then you call the method that will actually perform some work.
- Then you call a method that nobody knows what it does.
- Finally, you return the field value.

Is this method really worth it ?

Another remark would be on the method's name. Usually, you would choose a verb to start a method name, in order to know what the method is supposed to do...

Here is what I would have done :

```
public class MeterReading
{
    public double AccountId { get; set; }
    public DateTime MeterReadingDateTime { get; set; }
    public double MeterReadValue { get; set; }
}

public class MeterReadingsBase
{
    public List<MeterReading> MeterReadings { get; set; } = new List<MeterReading>();
    public int FailedParseReadings { get; set; }
}

public class MeterReadingsParseResult : MeterReadingsBase
{
}

public class MeterReadingsCsvProcessor
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Implements a new meter reading csv processor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="meterReadingsRepository">Unused parameter. Kept for retro compatibility</param>
    /// <param name="accountsRepository">Unused parameter. Kept for retro compatibility</param>
    public MeterReadingsCsvProcessor(IMeterReadingsRepository meterReadingsRepository, IAccountsRepository accountsRepository)
    {
    }

    public MeterReadingsParseResult ParseCsvFile(IFormFile file)
    {
        if (file == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(file));

        using (TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
        using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(textReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            return ParseCsv(csv);
        }
    }


    private MeterReadingsParseResult ParseCsv(CsvReader csv)
    {
        MeterReadingsParseResult parseResult = new MeterReadingsParseResult();
        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();

        CsvCustomErrorHandler<int> customInt32Converter = new CsvCustomErrorHandler<int>();

        while (csv.Read())
        {
            MeterReading reading = ReadOneValue(csv, customInt32Converter);
            if (reading == null)
            {
                parseResult.FailedParseReadings++;
            }
            else
            {
                parseResult.MeterReadings.Add(reading);
            }
        }
        return parseResult;
    }

    private MeterReading ReadOneValue(CsvReader csv, CsvCustomErrorHandler<int> customInt32Converter)
    {
        MeterReading reading = new MeterReading()
        {
            AccountId = csv.GetField<int>("AccountId"),
            MeterReadingDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(csv.GetField<string>("MeterReadingDateTime"), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            MeterReadValue = csv.GetField<int>("MeterReadValue", customInt32Converter)
        };
        if (reading.MeterReadValue < 1 || reading.MeterReadValue >= 100000)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return reading;
    }
}
```